# Insertion sort analysis and summation notation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, insertion

I am trying to understand the worst case analysis of Insertion sort and I have a problem with the math involved on [slide 21 (ppt)](http://www.cse.unr.edu/%7Ebebis/CS477/Lect/InsertionSortBubbleSortSelectionSort.ppt).

I understand the first formula:

[image: Σ(j=1 to n) j=n(n+1)/2]

But these I'm struggling with:

1. Why is there a `- 1` at the end?
   [image: Σ(j=2 to n) j=n(n+1)/2-1]
2. Also, I don't understand this one:
   [image: Σ(j=2 to n)(j-1) = n(n-1)/2]

Comment: Also much thanks to madflame991 for that amazing edit.

Comment: @Luuklag you a hero

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's Gauss' trick to sum numbers from 1 to n:

[image: trick of gauss]

### First formula

However, the sum you want to compute starts at `2`, not `1`, that is why you have to subtract the first term (i.e. 1) from the formula:

[image]

### Second formula

Essentially, you compute the sum from 1 until (n-1). If you substitute `n` in Gauss' trick with `n-1`, you receive the second formula they use.

You can also see this with an index transformation:

[image]

As you can see, I have adjusted the boundaries of the sum: Both the upper and lower bounds of the sum have been decreased by 1. Effectively, this deceases *all* terms in the sum by 1, to correct this, you have to add 1 to the term under the Σ: `(j-1) + 1` = `j`.

Comment: @steve jessop: Thanks to you too.

Comment: why do we divide by 2?

Comment: @KyelJmD If you sum the numbers 1 to 10, then you add `(1 + 10) + (2 + 9) + (3 + 8) + (4 + 7) + (5 + 6)`, that's five times 11. You divide by two, because when you have 10 numbers, and you group them in pairs of two, you end up with half as many pairs: 5. Does that help?

Comment: but why do we have to (1 + 10) and etc?  is this just a mathematical proof? but  I am getting it little by little.

Comment: @KyelJmD It's not a proof, I just reordered the numbers in the sum. Using a shorter example: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6`, reordering this, we have `1 + 6 + 2 + 5 + 3 + 4`, pairing, we have: `(1 + 6) + (2 + 5) + (3 + 4)`, evaluating the parens, we get: `7 + 7 + 7` which is `7*3` which is `7*6/2`, that's exctactly what the formula tells us.

Comment: @Luuklag you a hero

Answer (score 2):

`Σ(j=2 to n) j=n(n+1)/2-1` starts at 2 instead of 1. So it's the same terms added together 
except the 1. So the sum is 1 less.

`Σ(j=2 to n)(j-1)` is the same terms added together as `Σ(j=1 to n-1)(j)`. So to find its sum replace `n` with `n-1` in the formula `n(n+1)/2`.